# How to find a string inside of a string space insensitive?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, contains

For example if a string contains:

```
odfsdlkfn dskfThe Moonaosjfsl dflkfn
```

How can I check to see if it contains "The Moon"?

What I have currently been doing is (but does not work):

```
if string.find("The Moon")!=-1:
    doSomething
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `"The Moon" in string`?

Comment: "The Moon" in string ??

Comment: `if 'The Moon' in string`

Comment: @timgeb perhaps you can close this

Comment: @DevinGP when you say `(but does not work)` show us how its not working. It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
string = 'odfsdlkfn dskfThe Moonaosjfsl dflkfn'
if 'The Moon' in string:
    dosomething
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use regular expressions:

```
import re
text = "odfsdlkfn dskfThe Moonaosjfsl dflkfn"
if re.find("The Moon", text):
    ...
```

and in this case, you could ingore casing with `re(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)` if needed.

Comment: You might also want to explain when regex would be preferred over a simple `in`/`not in` check...